# how to implicitly convert a foo<const bar> into a const foo<bar> in C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++98, qualifiers

I'm making my own vector container and I'm trying to implement an iterator that works like the real one, using the C++98 standard.

This is homework so I don't want the answer just a hint as to where I should look and what I should learn to be able to tackle this problem.

So basically I'm trying to make this code work:

```
ft::vector<int> v (100, 100);
ft::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
ft::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = it;

std::cout << (cit == it) << std::endl; //comparison 1 /// works
std::cout << (it == cit) << std::endl; //comparison 2 /// doesn't compile
std::cout << (cit + 1 == it + 1) << std::endl; //doesn't work
std::cout << (it + 1 == cit + 1) << std::endl; //doesn't work
```

`iterator` and `const_iterator` are typedefs like this:

```
typedef typename ft::iterator_vector<value_type> iterator;
typedef typename ft::iterator_vector<const value_type> const_iterator;
```

And value type being the type passed to the vector template.

The first comparison didn't work until I added a user-defined conversion operator in my iterator template to convert <strike>`iterator<const foo>` into `iterator<foo>`</strike> (the other way around actually as pointed out by @TedLyngmo)
which is `operator iterator_vector<const value_type>() const { return _p; }`
but the compiler says that I need now to be able to convert a `iterator<const foo>` into a `const iterator<foo>` and I have no idea how to proceed.

This is the implementation of my iterator:

```
template <class T>
class iterator_vector : public ft::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {

public:

    typedef             ft::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>    iterator;
    typedef             ft::iterator_traits<iterator>                   iterator_traits;
    typedef typename    iterator_traits::difference_type                difference_type;
    typedef typename    iterator_traits::value_type                     value_type;
    typedef typename    iterator_traits::pointer                        pointer;
    typedef typename    iterator_traits::reference                      reference;
    typedef typename    iterator_traits::iterator_category              iterator_category;

    /*
    ** Member functions
    */

    iterator_vector(pointer p = 0) : _p(p) {}
    ~iterator_vector(void) {}

    operator iterator_vector<const value_type>() const { return _p; }

    iterator_vector& operator++() { ++_p; return *this; }
    iterator_vector operator++(int)
    {
        iterator_vector r = *this;
        ++_p;
        return r;
    }
    iterator_vector& operator--() { --_p; return *this; }
    iterator_vector operator--(int)
    {
        iterator_vector r = *this;
        --_p;
        return r;
    }
    iterator_vector operator+(size_t n) const { return iterator_vector(_p + n); }
    iterator_vector operator-(size_t n) const { return iterator_vector(_p - n); }
    iterator_vector& operator+=(size_t n) { _p += n; return *this; }
    iterator_vector& operator-=(size_t n) { _p -= n; return *this; }
    difference_type operator+(iterator_vector rhs) const { return _p + rhs._p; }
    difference_type operator-(iterator_vector rhs) const { return _p - rhs._p; }
    reference operator*(void) const { return *_p; }
    pointer operator->() const { return _p; }
    reference operator[](size_t n) const { return _p[n]; }
    bool operator==(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p == rhs._p; }
    bool operator!=(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p != rhs._p; }
    bool operator<(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p > rhs._p; }
    bool operator>(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p < rhs._p; }
    bool operator<=(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p <= rhs._p; }
    bool operator>=(const iterator_vector& rhs) const { return _p >= rhs._p; }

    /*
    ** Non-member functions
    */

    friend iterator_vector operator+(size_t n, const iterator_vector& rhs) { return iterator_vector(rhs._p + n); }
    friend iterator_vector operator-(size_t n, const iterator_vector& rhs) { return iterator_vector(rhs._p - n); }

private:

    pointer _p;

};
```

Comment: Usually you will have an "iterator" and a "const_iterator". Check out here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @Jellyboy what do you mean? I do have a const_iterator already. I use my iterator template but with iterator<const T> instead of iterator<T>. Do you mean I should have two separate class template and not reuse the same iterator template ?

Comment: @tvanbesi No, you should most probably not have two separate templates if you make template based iterators.

Comment: You don't want this conversion. You really really don't. Imagine what would happen if `const char*` was implicitly convertible to `char * const`. Iterators are fancy pointers, and should work like pointers.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I reacted to that too. I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your comments in your code about what is failing that you are missing a comparison function for when `iterator` is to the left and the `const_iterator` is to the right. You could add this free function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const iterator_vector<T>& lhs, const iterator_vector<const T>& rhs) {
    // just swap the order here and the implicit conversion from `iterator`
    // to `const_iterator` from `lhs` solves the rest:
    return rhs == lhs;
}
```

> I added a user-defined conversion operator in my iterator template to convert `iterator<const foo>` into `iterator<foo>`

No, you added an implicit conversion the other way around. That is, from `iterator` to `const_iterator` - which is good!

---

An alternative could be to make the two iterators `friend`s to not have to implement similar swapping *lhs* with *rhs* functions for all your operators. The operators in your template would then become:

```cpp
// define these before your class template (borrowed from C++11):
template< class T > struct remove_const          { typedef T type; };
template< class T > struct remove_const<const T> { typedef T type; };
```

```
//... in your class template:
friend class iterator_vector<typename remove_const<T>::type>;
friend class iterator_vector<const T>;

template<typename U>
bool operator==(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p == rhs._p; }
template<typename U>
bool operator!=(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p != rhs._p; }
template<typename U>
bool operator<(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p > rhs._p; }
template<typename U>
bool operator>(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p < rhs._p; }
template<typename U>
bool operator<=(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p <= rhs._p; }
template<typename U>
bool operator>=(const iterator_vector<U>& rhs) const { return _p >= rhs._p; }
```

Comment: What about all other comparison operators? Does OP need to add them too?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, OP would need swapping functions for all operators. I added an alternative.

Comment: @TedLyngmo And thanks again for the details you added in your edit, but my code must be compatible with the c++98 standard so I won't use remove_const, but maybe I can implement it myself (something with SFINAE I guess)

Comment: @tvanbesi Just add the definitions of `remove_const` I put in the answer. They are C++98 compatible. They are just not the `std::remove_const` you get when including `<type_traits>` in later C++ standards. You can put them in your `ft` namespace if you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Perfect :)

Comment: If you accidentally compare two unrelated iterators, the error message could be rather cryptic. You can "fix" it (sort of) this way https://godbolt.org/z/1KK6TjqTo even though it is probably an overkill.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yeah, I know - it's meant to give the same feeling one often got when templates were involved back in -98 :-) Nah, seriously, thanks for the suggestion to make error messages clearer. I'll leave it up to OP to incorporate that into the iterator template..